# Hierarchical select in Entity Framework with lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, rbac

I have a relational dataset as dummy. I want to take the data as hierarchical (Role > SubRoles > Permissions) then I will convert to JSON but I get an exception:

> Error CS0266
>   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Thanks for your answer.

Model classes:

```
    public class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SubRole> SubRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubRole
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EndPoint { get; set; }
        public List<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleSubRole
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public int SubRoleId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Permission
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubRolePermission
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SubRoleId { get; set; }
        public int PermiisonId { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleModel
    {
        public Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Program class:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RoleModel roleModel = new RoleModel()
        {
            Role =
            (from u in DataSet.Users
             join r in DataSet.Roles on u.RoleId equals r.Id
             where u.Id == 1
             select new Role
             {
                 Name = r.Name,
                 SubRoles =
                 (from rsb in DataSet.RoleSubRoles
                 join sr in DataSet.SubRoles on rsb.SubRoleId equals sr.Id
                 where r.Id == rsb.RoleId
                 select new SubRole
                 {
                      Name = sr.Name,
                      EndPoint = sr.EndPoint,
                      Permissions =
                      (from srp in DataSet.SubRolePermissions
                      join p in DataSet.Permissions on srp.PermiisonId equals p.Id
                      where srp.SubRoleId == sr.Id
                      select new Permission
                      {
                          Name = p.Name
                      })
                 })
             })
        };
    }
```

Comment: You can use `AsEnumerable`. I am not familiar with the query expression syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
Permissions =
                      (from srp in DataSet.SubRolePermissions
                      join p in DataSet.Permissions on srp.PermiisonId equals p.Id
                      where srp.SubRoleId == sr.Id
                      select new Permission
                      {
                          Name = p.Name
                      }).ToList()
```

The Permissions is a `List<T>`, while the query returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. Same is the case with SubRoles.You need to convert to `List<T>`, which could be done using the `ToList()` method

Complete Query

```
Role =
            (from u in DataSet.Users
             join r in DataSet.Roles on u.RoleId equals r.Id
             where u.Id == 1
             select new Role
             {
                 Name = r.Name,
                 SubRoles =
                 (from rsb in DataSet.RoleSubRoles
                 join sr in DataSet.SubRoles on rsb.SubRoleId equals sr.Id
                 where r.Id == rsb.RoleId
                 select new SubRole
                 {
                      Name = sr.Name,
                      EndPoint = sr.EndPoint,
                      Permissions =
                      (from srp in DataSet.SubRolePermissions
                      join p in DataSet.Permissions on srp.PermiisonId equals p.Id
                      where srp.SubRoleId == sr.Id
                      select new Permission
                      {
                          Name = p.Name
                      }).ToList()
                 }).ToList()
             }).First()
        };
```

Also note that the Role represents a single entity, while the query returns a collection. You need to make a choice on which entity from the collection needs to be stored. For the sample code above, I have used `First()`

Comment: It's worked. Thanks. I used ToLİst for Permiisons,SubRoles and I used FirstOrDefault  for Role